# Load csv data to cassandra inside docker from another ec2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have two instances on AWS ec2. In one of the instance I have installed Cassandra inside docker container and now I want to load csv data to Cassandra from another ec2. so can i directly insert data to Cassandra without copying file from one ec2 to another ec2(ce2 with cassendra)?
or do i need to first copy file to another ec2(ec2 with cassendra) and then go for insertion?.

i have used this commands to install cassandra inside docker:

```
docker network create cassandra-net
docker run --name my-cassandra --network cassandra-net -d cassandra:latest
```

I can access cqlsh using this command:

```
docker run -it --rm --network cassandra-net cassandra:latest cqlsh my-cassandra
```

I am new on docker so can someone please explain with example.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting cassandra on your 1st EC2(x.x.x.x) instance with commmand

```
docker run --name my-cassandra --network cassandra-net -d cassandra:latest
```

pass network as host

```
docker run --name my-cassandra --network host -d cassandra:latest
```

i.e it will use your host network to expose cassandra and then on your second EC2(y.y.y.y) instance just use the cqlsh command to connect to cassandra on host1.

```
cqlsh x.x.x.x
```

Now you are connected to cassandra on host 1 and can copy the CSV directly from host2.

Comment: using above command i got error "docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for cassandra-net, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied." so i use this command "docker run --name my-cassandra --network host cassandra" but now process is stuck in uninterruptible

Comment: Okay so I didn't saw that you created another network named cassandra-net which you used n your command you can create the cassandra container using  docker run --name my-cassandra --network host -d cassandra:latest

Comment: The command I posted is working perfectly fine for me

Comment: above command is working and i can access cqlsh also but i need to provide native_transport_port: with the command like this: "cqlsh x.x.x.x 9842" so is it good idea to provoid this port?

Comment: and one more problem is on fresh ec2 instance with above command cassandra.yaml file is not created

Comment: Yes there is no problem to give port but I think it will always try connecting by default on port 9042. Also your cassandra is running inside docker container on host 1 so to access it on host 2 using cqlsh command you will need to install the standalone cqlsh tool using https://docs.datastax.com/en/install/6.7/install/installCqlsh.html

Comment: so problem was just about ec2 security group ie. providing permissions to ec2. now its working fine thank you for your help